# How to use Promise in Service AngularJS? Sample Data Firebase

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firebase

Here is my service.js file:

```
    angular.module('starter.services', [])
    .factory('firebaseData', function() {
       return {
          refUserFacebook: function (userUid) {
            var firebaseRef =  new Firebase("https://sweltering-heat-772.firebaseio.com/users/");
            var user;
            firebaseRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
                var users = dataSnapshot.val();
                var userKeys = Object.keys(users);
                for (var i = 0, len = userKeys.length; i < len; i ++){
                    if (users[userKeys[i]].uid == userUid){
                        user = users[userKeys[i]];
                    }
                }
                console.log(user);
                return user;
            });
          }
        }
     })
```

Here is my controller file name item.js file

```
angular.module('starter.controllers.item', [])

.controller('ItemCtrl', function($scope, firebaseData) {

    var ref = firebaseData.ref();
    var userUid = ref.getAuth();
    var user = firebaseData.refUserFacebook(userUid.uid);
    console.log(user);

})
```

Of course I'll get undefined in the item.js controller first, and user in service return after.

I'd really like to use Promise technology in my controller, to return user value from the service.

In item.js file, it would be something like:

```
firebaseData.refUserFacebook(userUid.uid).then(function(user){
   console.log(user); //Promise after retrieving value from service.js
});
```

Any helps would be appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Next time you should provide at least some code of your attempt... but here's what you want:

```
angular.module('starter.services', [])
.factory('firebaseData', function($q) {
   return {
      refUserFacebook: function (userUid) {
        var firebaseRef =  new Firebase("https://sweltering-heat-772.firebaseio.com/users/");
        var user;
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        firebaseRef.once('value', function(dataSnapshot) {
            var users = dataSnapshot.val();
            var userKeys = Object.keys(users);
            for (var i = 0, len = userKeys.length; i < len; i ++){
                if (users[userKeys[i]].uid == userUid){
                    user = users[userKeys[i]];
                }
            }
            console.log(user);
            deferred.resolve(user);
        });
        return deferred.promise;
      }
    }
 })
```

Comment: Thanks, working perfectly. :) Will do next time. Cheers